# Help wanted in evaluating an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics

Trying to evaluate an integral. To be specific, I'm trying to find the expectation value of $x^2$ for the ground state of hydrogen. Here is the code I used:

```
FullSimplify[
  Integrate[x^2/(Pi*a^3) E^((-2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])/a), {x,-Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

The odd part is it worked when I calculated $\left<x\right>$, i.e. just drop an $x$ from the first fraction.

Comment: Did you try letting _Mathematica_ know that $a$ is real, say with `Assuming[]` ?

Comment: Just did, no such luck:(

Comment: Then I'd try to convert the integral into spherical coordinates (although it is disappointing that _M_ didn't try it).

Comment: Try a change of coordinate cartesian-spherical.

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the proper way to do the problem anyway.

Comment: you probably need to specify `assuming` `a>0` and maybe `y,z Real`..